# Foreach not executing right...... PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

```
<?php 
    $i = 0;
    $images = get_field('bildspel');

    if( $images ):  
    if( is_array( $images )) {
        foreach( $images as $image ): 
            print($image);
        ?>
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />
        </div>
        <?php
        endforeach;
    }
 endif; ?>
```

I have tried both with the is_array if statement and without. If I go without it I get the following error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in-.....

What am I doing wrong?

Im trying to loop out an array of images from ACF - wordpress.

Comment: please post what is the data you have in images

Comment: So basicly after dumping the data it seems to be a string...
string '
  <style type='text/css'>
   #gallery-1 {
    margin: auto;
   }
   #gallery-1 .gallery-item {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
   }
   #gallery-1 img {
    border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
   }
   #gallery-1 .gallery-caption {
    margin-left: 0;
   }
   /* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */
  </style>
  <div id='gallery-1' class='gallery galleryid-35 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-thumbnail'><dl class='gallery-item'>
   <dt class='gallery-icon land'... (length=1485)

Comment: So you need to go back to where the value is set if you're retrieving a string. The above code isn't the problem, and as in my answer - you're trying to loop something that isn't an array.

Comment: @Jigar is leading you in the correct direction. You need to evaluate `$images` and will, no doubt, discover that it is not an array. However, I want to ask how you are developing your code. Are you just using an editor, or are you using an IDE? [Print debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging) does work, but it not the proper way to go about it. Get yourself a good IDE (for instance  [Eclipse PDT](https://eclipse.org/pdt/)) and learn how to set a breakpoint and evaluate variables, without changing your code.

Answer (score 2):

You have pretty much answered your own question:

> I have tried both with the is_array if statement and without. If I go
>   without it I get the following error:
>
> > Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in-.....

The answer is that `$images` is not an array. You need to check that `bildspel` is actually set. Are you sure that it's the right name? Is it set correctly elsewhere?

Answer (score -2):

I posted the above code into my editor and it told me there were errors - perhaps it doesn't understand that particular syntax style I don't know but the following might work?

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $images = get_field('bildspel');

    if( $images && is_array( $images ) && !empty( $images ) ) {
        foreach( $images as $image ){
            /*print( $image );*/
            echo "
                <div class='item active'>
                    <img src='{$image['url']}' />
                </div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why not also check for `!= false` and `isset($images[0])` and `true != false`? In other words: you're overdoing it with checks here for no gain whatsoever.

Comment: @deceze - do those extra check cause any issues other not being the way you would do it?

Comment: @deceze - genuine question

Comment: As I said: it's useless. It adds more unnecessary stuff. It makes the code harder to read and maintain. Every additional character in your code is a potential bug; you should aim to write as little as possible to get the job done properly. `if (is_array($images))` is perfectly sufficient in this situation. The additional checks are redundant, misplaced and don't add any value.